# Do CompositeViews automatically re-render when the collection is sync'ed?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I construct a CompositeView by passing it a collection. The collection gets its data via a url. I'm using the defer/promise technique to wait till the collection is populated before constructing the View.

Later I call fetch on the collection again, modifying the url.

To my surprise the CompositeView is re-rendered with the new data in the Collection. I thought I would have to do something e.g.:

```
collectionEvents: {
    "sync" : "render"

}
```

But I'm not doing anything. No event binding at all. I thought in marionette I would have to handle this 'manually'.

This looks like something to do with [CollectionView: Automatic Rendering](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionview-automatic-rendering). Does this happen with models and item views as well? And why do some tutorials etc. explain about binding?

Thanks

--Justin Wyllie

Answer (score 1):

Yes but the only thing that will be re-rendered will be the collection, if you are using a CompositeView to display a model and a collection, the model part will not be re-rendered, you have to set an event for that.
So the CompositeView has the same behavior of the collectionView and it will re-render the collection whenever theres a change in the data.

And to your second question this does not happens in the ItemViews when the model changes.
this you have to do it on your own when its best for you application needs.